# Redirect Rule in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

What rule should I write for redirection in htaccess so that

`http://abc.com/http://xyz.com/path/` redirects to `http://xyz.com/path/`

but

`http://abc.com/?url=http://xyz.com/path/` should not redirect

Thanks,
Loveleen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important thing to remember for this kind of redirection is that Apache strips out all multiple slashes in RewriteRule match. For this reason it is better to use variable `%{THE_REQUEST}` which remains "as is". SO just use this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(https?://[^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R]
```